# Console colorizing AWK script does not work on cmd.exe

Tags: windows, awk, cmd, console

I wrote an AWK script, so that while launching my python scripts, stout is being colorized. Fine, it works, but only while using cygwin.
For some reason I have to use win7 cmd.exe. I installed gawk for win but it does not work:

python script.py | awk -f colorize.awk

here is my output

```
←[0;0;34m????? >[10:24:04.623000]: Device amount = 3←[0;0;37m←[0;0;37m
```

I would appreciate any usefull hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colorizing cmd.exe does not work like this, it does not take ANSI escape sequences. The only thing you can do to colorize would be using the `COLOR` command. See here: http://ss64.com/nt/color.html

Comment: What would you suggest to use instead of cmd.exe?

Comment: If you want to use what youve already got then Cygwin of course. But you wrote you cannot. You might have a look at Microsoft Powershell, but im not into that enough to tell you if thats capable of ANSI escape sequences.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your shell (i.e. cmd.exe or powershell.exe). You're running python.exe and awk.exe. Both are console applications that have a handle to a console hosted by conhost.exe. Every character cell in the console has a color attribute. The Win32 API to write to the console i.e. `WriteConsole` or `WriteFile` doesn't handle ANSI escape sequences; it's up to the application to call, for example, `SetConsoleTextAttribute`. It's possible to inject a DLL into a process to hook these APIs. For example, try [ANSICON](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon).